# Client/server communication is blocked by firewall

Tags: sockets, client, firewall

I am running an online game site in which the users login to the web site and open a game client (Java applet) that communicates with the game server (also written in Java) by opening a socket connection to port 3000 of the same host.

There is a problem with this model in that sometimes the client network has firewall rules that block all ports except for port 80. So in effect the particular user can browse and login to the web site, but he cannot play because the connection to port 3000 is blocked.

I am looking for a solution to this issue and hope to hear suggestions from anyone who has had a similar experience.

Many thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1):

Can you use somesubdomain.yourhost.com:80 instead of yourhost.com:3000?

Comment: I haven't thought of using subdomain but for this to work does somesubdomain.yourhost.com have to point to a different IP address than yourhost.com?

Comment: @user751103 As you wish, you can setup dns configuration to have same or different ip. You also can have many different domains in one ip.

Comment: I guess my question is that if domain and subdomain have the same IP address then would yourhost.com:80 be different than somesubdomain.yourhost.com:80 from the client's view? Remember that the web server is already running at yourhost:80...